# Making a popup image with focus on css and limited Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been searching for a way to make a popup image with limited javascript. I have found css only solutions, but "hover" and "active" doesn't work in this setting. I need a "onclick" solution, but the task is more css focused.

I need the finished results to look as much like this as possible, but with onlick and not active.

## html:

```
<div id="thumbwrap">
<a class="thumb"><img src="telefon.png" style="height: 200px;
width: 126px;" alt="Hvordan ringe" onclick="myFunction()"><span>
<img src="telefon.png" style="height: 500px; width: 315px;" alt="">
</span></a>
</div>
```

## css:

```
#thumbwrap {
position: relative;
margin: 75px;
}

.thumb img { 
border: 1px solid #000;
margin: 3px;
float: left;
height: 400px;
width: 250px;
}

.thumb span { 
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
margin-left: -100px;
}

.thumb:active, .thumb:active span { 
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 250px; 
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Remove those extra `#` symbols from the start of each line of your CSS

Comment: you could try a bootstrap modal

Answer (score 0):

Your active selector needs to be here like this.

```
.thumb img:active { 
border: 1px solid #000;
margin: 3px;
float: left;
height: 400px;
width: 250px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of replacing your current solution using the `:active` pseudo class would be to change the css rules that are currently set to the `:active` pseudo class to a class (I've called it `.active` to keep things as similar to your original code as possible).

You will then simply need to toggle the class on/off on the thumbnail using JavaScript as follows:

```
var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("thumb");

for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
    thumbs[i].addEventListener("click", showBigImage);
}

function showBigImage() {
    if (this.className.indexOf("active") > -1) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    else {
        this.className = this.className + " active";
    }
}
```

There's a full fiddle using the code that you posted here: https://jsfiddle.net/stecag24/